# How to add values from a dropdown box into a Mysql query?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a drop-down box where you can select the following:

"Today"
"Last 7 Days"

MySQL Query is:

```
Dim x1 As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=test;PWD=test;")
x1.Open()
Dim comx1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE AffID = '" & CType(Session.Item("affID"), String) & "' AND CompletedDate= '" & DropDownList1.Text & "'", x1)
Dim myReaderx1 As MySqlDataReader = comx1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
myReaderx1.Read()
Label12.Text = myReaderx1.Item(0).ToString()
```

The value for today in the dropbox is supposed to be " CURDATE() "

So the query is supposed to look like this :

```
Dim x1 As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=test;PWD=test;")
x1.Open()
Dim comx1 As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome WHERE AffID = '" & CType(Session.Item("affID"), String) & "' AND CompletedDate = CURDATE() ", x1)
Dim myReaderx1 As MySqlDataReader = comx1.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
myReaderx1.Read()
Label12.Text = myReaderx1.Item(0).ToString()
```

How do I do this?
Fill `DropDownList1.Text` with the values in the Dropbox.

Comment: So far 2 people have edited the question, and no-one has tryed to answer it or assist. If you cant assist, please dont waist my time. Stackoverflow is also for people like me needing assistance and to educate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim commandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM toutcome " & _
                 "WHERE AffID = '" & CType(Session.Item("affID"), String) & "' AND CompletedDate = @init "
        Using c = New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=test;UID=test;PWD=test;")
            Using com = New MySqlCommand(commandText, c)
                c.Open()
                com.Parameters.Add("@init", MySqlDbType.String).Value = Convert.ToString(DropDownList1.Text)
                Using myReader = com.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
                    If myReader.Read() Then
                        Label11.Text = myReader.Item(0).ToString()

                        myReader.Close()
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```